# Why electromagnetic waves propagating along x transfers to electron momentum along z?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electromagnetism, momentum

Why EM waves having only x momentum transfers to electron z momentum? Electron begins oscillating along z, so will not radiate EM waves along z direction, to compensate its z momentum. It seems that it is violated conservation of momentum?

Comment: For the opposite process, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11904/2451

Comment: Why do You ask the same question two times?  Were the answers out of Your reach?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/why-photons-transfer-to-electrons-perpendicular-momentum

Comment: There is no correct answer

Answer (score 1):

In the particle formulation of electromagnetism, light is carried by photons. Momentum is absolutely conserved. If a photon hits an electron, there will be momentum balance.

In the wave formulation of EM the electric field,( supposed it is a polarized beam),  oscillates in the z direction. An electron that acquires a momentum will take part of the energy of the beam and the beam will acquire a small z component to conserve momentum. On the average,since the electron will be hit in both z directions by the incoming beam, the effect will be that the beam will spread/degrade, to conserve momentum and energy.

Comment: From your explanation it follows that if we consider in terms of photons, the electron will acquire mainly x momentum (cos(teta) from x direction), if consider in terms of waves, electron will acquire mainly z momentum (cos(teta) from z direction). What will be in reality?

Comment: @grigori No. One has to solve the specific scattering  with Feynman diagrams that are consistent with both the wave and particle picture to see what a specific scatter will do. You have to give the energy of the photon etc to speak about what "an electron will acquire", and that will be probabilistic. If we are talking about optical frequency photons on electrons at rest the amount of momentum and energy transfered will be minimal:

Comment: continued:a small delta(p_z)+delta(p_x) for the electron which will almost remain at rest and the photon will be steered a tiny bit away from the x direction. That is what I meant by dispersion of the beam

Comment: anna, no. The amount of transfered momentum can be large if we use strong optical frequency waves. By this oscillating along z electron will not radiate along z, so its z momentum is not compensated by radiated field.

Comment: Do you have a link to this claim? A specific experiment?

Comment: Usual radiwaves with frequency ~100kHz and E field ~0.1V/m acts on electron with the force ~10E-20N, and during time ~10E-5sec electron will shifted on ~ meters.In stronger EM fields it can be used even small charged particles. There is no quantum effects here.

Comment: @grigori lets try again. You are talking about momentum acquired by a single electron in a beam in a direction that seems strange to you. By definition it is a quantum problem.The energy of the photon in a 100kherz beam is 6.6X10^-29joule. (E=h*nu) . With such small numbers the heisenberg uncertainty principle holds, i.e delta(p)*delta(x)<hbar is uncertain within hbar: the momentum and the position (zdirection) are indeterminate for the specific electron within the uncertainty principle bounds and there is no problem with momentum conservation.For accuracy see my answer.

Comment: anna, it is not quantum problem. We can use stronger E field up to E~1000V/m, lower frequency ~10kHz, and take instead of electron a small peace of charged material dimensions ~0.1mm mass ~10E-9kg, q~10E-8Culon. There is no heizenberg uncertainity here. We can see that this peace is in rest, and when EM wave come, the peace will shifted ~1cm perpendicularly to EM wave wavevector (momentum)

Comment: @grigori then you are not talking of one electron. The classical description should suffice. There exists an angular momentum component in the classical em field, depending on the type of radiation ( dipole etc), and the energy your charged piece picks up will be depleted from the em beam. I would expect it would be vibrating if in space,i.e. free to move.Momentum will be conserved by radiating electromagnetically itself according to its motion.

Comment: anna, plane em wave is determined only by wave vector and amplitude of E, there is no angular momentum.2) charge does not radiate along direction of oscillation (z axis), so radiating field can not compensate its z momentum.

Comment: @grigori I think the problem is conceptual and arises from mixing up two frameworks, classical and QM. There is no problem in the QM. In the classical, if you have a micron size, lets say particle, it will be composed of very many atoms and molecules all bound electromagnetically to each other.Lets say it is hovering in space and a plane wave passes it. It will oscilate and take part of the beam energy and momentum will be compensated within its zillions of molecules ending up finally in radiated heat .Since the wave has equal strength in both z directions it will oscillate in place.

Comment: continued: in the solid state picture of what is happening within this oscillating small particle, there will be positive "holes" running the other way when the negative charges follow a field, compensating momentum and also able to take up excess for balance.