# What does an electromagnetic wave look like at a fixed moment in time?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I am curious what the electric and magnetic field's of light look like when time is stopped. A "photograph" or illustration/description of these fields at a moment in time is what I desire.

Also, does the picture change at various points in the wave?

I assume that [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/popular-depictions-of-electromagnetic-wave-is-there-an-error) is like a "time exposure" of a light wave.

Comment: I suggest to change the title (v1) into the less dramatic _What does an electromagnetic wave look like at a fixed instant of time?_

Comment: @Qmechanic: good idea, done ;-) Feel free to make those edits yourself when you can do it without changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Joe, No, the link you gave is not a time exposure of a light wave.  It is a depiction of the electric and magnetic fields at different places at the same time - exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @Mark Eichenlaub  Surely there is a defined length (z-direction if E and B are in x and y) to the sinusoidal wave depiction of light.

Comment: @Joe Of course there is, and it is already drawn into the picture and clearly labeled with the word "wavelength".

Comment: @Mark Eighenlaub Is there a reason why more than one wavelength is shown in most depictions?

Comment: @Joe Why not  show more than one?  I think the main motivation is that it just looks nicer to draw two or three wavelengths.  If you have something like a laser beam going several meters, there will be millions of wavelengths along the length of the beam.

Comment: @Mark Eighenlaub I have been confused about this for years (after 4 semesters of calculus based college physics all As and Bs). Showing only one wavelength would likely have conveyed the concept to me more clearly

Comment: @Mark Eighenlaub If you would put your comments in an answer I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the graphic in [Lubos Motl's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/why-photons-transfer-to-electrons-perpendicular-momentum/10918#10918) to another electromagnetic question.

It shows a  polarised plane wave propagating in time and you can take a time projection that answers your question. Unpolarised plane waves have all possible orientations in space.

Answer (score -3):

It's like a sine wave. If you plot a sine wave on graph paper, from 0 - 1. You can see it.

I've honestly seen no explanation, that I understood, that explained the exact the exact correlation, but, mathematically, it's a perfect fit.

Oh, you might want to use 'polar plot' graphing paper. It makes the mathematics trivial.

Comment: Could you explain what the axis labels would be if you were to make such a graph?